# What is the best way to loop through object array using javaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

What is the best way to loop through the below object?

```
object {
   ATR: [object {
     company:'Apple',
     funded: 'Yes',
     funding: 'Expected',
     program: 'ATR'
   },object {
     company:'Google',
     funded: 'Yes',
     funding: 'Expected',
     program: 'ATR'
   }],
   QTR: [object {
     company:'Apple',
     funded: 'Yes',
     funding: 'Expected',
     program: 'QTR'
   }],
   RES:[],
   STR: [object {
     company:'Apple',
     funded: 'Yes',
     funding: 'Expected',
     program: 'STR'
   },object {
     company:'Google',
     funded: 'Yes',
     funding: 'Expected',
     program: 'STR'
   }]
}
```

I tried the following code but it just returned an empty array.  My goal is to be able to loop through the data and show a table grouped by 'program' property.

```
function loopThrough(data){
  for (key in data){
    console.log(data[key])
  }
}
```

Here's the [pen](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/LYPWoyW?editors=0012)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Your codepen has output in the console.

Comment: Why do you think it's just showing an empty array.

Comment: There is no "best way". It's also quite unclear what xou want to achieve here ... Have a look at the dupe for some ways to iterate objects, arrays, etc.

Comment: It's showing an empty array for `RES` because the response doesn't have anything for that key.

Comment: Solved it, you need to use `reduce` properly to achieve that https://codepen.io/aganglada/pen/KKPWOKX?editors=0012

Comment: Thanks for the solution @AlejandroGarciaAnglada but unfortunately, es6 does not work in IE 11.  I will use babel to convert it.  Hopefully that works.  Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, expected, you could fo that, or change spread operator to `Object.assign`